# Weld with Tomcat : WELD-000714, WELD-000715, WELD-000335

Tags: jax-rs, tomcat7, cdi, weld, jboss-weld

I am using WELD 2.4.1.Final for my web application running on Tomcat 7. I am having JSF and Jax-RS Rest services in my web application. I have implemented asynchronous JAX-RS Rest Services. Async Rest call works perfect, but in logs I got following Warnings :

```
WELD-000715: HttpContextLifecycle guard not set. The Servlet container is not fully compliant. 
WELD-000714: HttpContextLifecycle guard leak detected. The Servlet container is not fully compliant. The value was 1 
WELD-000335: Conversation context is already active, most likely it was not cleaned up properly during previous request processing
```

I got from this website : http://weld.cdi-spec.org/documentation/, that these are issues from Tomcat.

Should I consider them or just ignore? If I ignore, does it affect performance of my web app? Is there any **Workaround** to get rid of this warnings?

Comment: The documentation you mentioned also points to the exact "bug" where this was discussed. I think you can find your answers [there](https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=57314). Other additional configuration that might interest you is in Weld doc itself. [Chapter 18.3.1 - Tomcat](http://docs.jboss.org/weld/reference/latest/en-US/html_single/#_tomcat)

Comment: @Siliarus - I don't find any answer in provided links.